# Cannot load such file -- 2.4/bcrypt_ext

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, bcrypt-ruby

I am trying to run `rails s` on my project but when I do this error pops up:

```
C:/ror/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/mysql2-0.4.10-x64-mingw32/lib/mysql2/2.4/mysql2.so: warning: constant ::TimeoutError is deprecated
rails aborted!
LoadError: cannot load such file -- bcrypt_ext
c:/ror/dev/AWI/config/application.rb:8:in `<top (required)>'
c:/ror/dev/AWI/Rakefile:5:in `require_relative'
c:/ror/dev/AWI/Rakefile:5:in `<top (required)>'
bin/rails:4:in `require'
bin/rails:4:in `<main>'

Caused by:
LoadError: cannot load such file -- 2.4/bcrypt_ext
c:/ror/dev/AWI/config/application.rb:8:in `<top (required)>'
c:/ror/dev/AWI/Rakefile:5:in `require_relative'
c:/ror/dev/AWI/Rakefile:5:in `<top (required)>'
bin/rails:4:in `require'
bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

When I look at the gem list I have `bcrypt (3.1.12, 3.1.11 x64-mingw32)` installed.

My Gemfile had this gem in it `gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'` and I switched it to `gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.11'` which still didn't work.

I am running this project using Ruby 2.4.2, Rails 5.1.4, mysql 8.0.11. Any ideas on how I can get my `rails s` command to operate.

Comment: check https://github.com/codahale/bcrypt-ruby/issues/142 and try AliOsm solution